# How can I drop relations in a PostgreSQL database without foreign key check?

Tags: postgresql

I need to create and delete tables in a test database while in development stage, but foreign keys verification bores me every time I need to erase its tables.

Is there any form to bypass this in Postgresql?

Comment: Do you `delete` rows? Or do you `drop` the tables? It's unclear to me based on your question

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name I hadn't seen your comment.
I'm sorry if I was not clear. But I've solved.
Thank you for your disposition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've got it.

For a single table I can do:

```
DROP TABLE "tableName" CASCADE
```

For all tables inside a schema, for example "public", I can do:

```
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA public;
```

Source:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droptable.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13823560/937110

Or, as suggested by a_horse_with_no_name:

```
DROP OWNED BY name [, ...] [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]
```

source:
http://postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-drop-owned.html

Comment: There is also `drop owned by` that drop all objects owned by a user. Are you _really_ still using Postgres 8.2?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL: 9.4.4 through PHPpgsql under Vagrant.
I'm creating tables for testing and then I erase them. If you have a better solution I'm listening you.

Comment: Not necessarily better, but an alternative: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-drop-owned.html

Comment: It's a good alternative. Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. I think I'll use this.